# How to apply a function on all 2x2 blocks in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I hope to apply an function on all 2x2 blocks in a numpy 2-D array. how could I do that?],

For example:

Input Array:

```
[[A(0,0), A(0,1), ... A(0,n-1)],
 [A(1,0), A(1,1), ... A(1,n-1)],
 ...
 [A(m-1,0), A(m-1,1), ... A(m-1, n-1)]]
```

where (n%2 == 0) and (m%2 == 0)

I hope to apply a function as below (fox example) to this input array:

```
C1*A(x,y) + C2*A(x+1,y) - C3*A(x,y+1) - C4*A(x+1,y+1)
```

where (x=2i, y=2j, 0<=x<=m/2, 0<=j<=n/2)

The output should be an (m/2)x(n/2) array.

Thanks

Comment: Some code, expected output, input, or anything that can make it's possible to understand your question?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(16).reshape((4,4))
c1=c2=c3=c4=1
print a
print c1*a[::2,::2] + c2*a[1::2,::2] - c3*a[::2,1::2] - c4*a[1::2,1::2]
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
[[-2 -2]
 [-2 -2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter is almost what you want.  It will overlap what they call the 'footprint' where you want a non-overlapping version.  What you could do is use generic_filter for the calculation and then subset to get the array you want.

You don't give example data so I will make some up...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

def myfilter(footprint_vals, c1, c2, c3, c4):
    return sum(np.array([c1, c2, -c3, -c4]) * footprint_vals)

footprint = [[False, True,  False],
             [True,  False, True],
             [False, True, False]]

old_array = np.arange(120).reshape((6,20))

c1 = 2
c2 = 4
c3 = 2
c4 = 8
new_array = scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(old_array, myfilter,
            footprint=footprint, extra_arguments=(c1,c2,c3,c4))
```

That should get you close...

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing at what you want because your question is not very clear. I am assuming you want to call a function with the input as a position in the array and apply the output to that position within the array. There might be a better way to do this, but this is what I came up with off the top of my head.

```
a = arange(4).reshape(2,2)

for row in range(a.shape[0]):
    for col in range(a.shape[1]):
        a[row,col] = 0 #exchange this for any function you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean with a 2-d array that's of even dimension in both axes?

You could place each 2x2 block into a row like this:

```
a = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
a2 = np.hstack((a[::2].reshape((-1,2)), a[1::2].reshape((-1,2))))
```

Then apply a function like this:

```
np.sum(a2, axis=1)
```

**EDIT: to apply the function added in the question**

```
c = np.array([C1,C2,-C3,-C4])
a3 = np.sum(a2 * c, axis=1)
a3.reshape(np.array(a.shape) / 2)
```